# Directory structure in a project of computational physics

Tags: directory, structure, project, physics, directory-structure

### Current situation

My scientific project contains mainly different analytical and numerical calculations with physics purpose, i.e. I work with Mathematica, MATLAB, Fortran. Of course it is a good idea to commit the progress with a version control program like git.

I was asking some friends what would be the best way to structure my files. Beside the simple and well-known programmer's file structure (`/bin/`,`/dat/`,`/doc/`,`/src/`,...), I found no satisfying but similar answers:

- [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193161/2062965)
- [Directory structure for a C++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398445/2062965)
- [Web Application (Django) typical project folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2282034/2062965)
- [Proper folder structure for lots of source files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8640789/2062965)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7715704/2062965

I hope this issue is not getting closed as it is asked by a physicist ;) as I guess many scientists are facing the same question at some point in more or less extension. By knowing that programmers have faced such issues before, I do not ask this question at [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/about), where it could probably be marked as `off-topic` or `too broad`.

### Example

In my last project I had the following global structure where I had some interaction between the different project items:

```
/External_Code_Contribution/
/Experimental_Data/
/Analytical_Calculations/
  /Project_Issue_1/
  /Project_Issue_5/
/Documentations/
  /Thesis/
  /Papers/
  /Talks/
/Literature/
/Project_Organization/
/Numerical_Calculations/
  /Project_Issue_1/
    /SubIssue_A/
    /SubIssue_B/
    /SubIssue_C/
  /Project_Issue_2/
  /Project_Issue_3/
  /Project_Issue_4/
  /Project_Issue_6/
```

**Description:**
In this project I divided the files according their **functionality** (external contribution, exp. data, numerics, documentation,...) and then subdivided them according to their **issue** (what was calculated at that step) where each issue again contained **subissues** (e.g. for analogous calculations with a different data set) with source code, binaries and processed data (for simplicity all in the same directory).

Unfortunately in this approach I ether had to:

- refer to the source code in the corresponding issue (danger of changing anything can lead to incompatibilities), or
- copy the source code to each new issue (each source code file with same name but in a different folder could be different).

### Question

Who faced this issue of structuring projects in directories? Please tell me your approach and the arguments that brought you to this structure!

(**Possible addition:** What should I keep in mind when I set up a file structure for a project as described above?)

If you do not completely understand the answer, please do not hesitate to ask instead of flagging. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think a clean algorithm exists for organizing files into a directory structure. But there's a narrower (and therefore answerable) question in the middle there: how to deal with several data sets, all going through similar -- but not identical -- calculations. Would that be worth pursuing?

Comment: It is definitely worth pursuing with the narrower question. I am just not fully sure whether I understand what you mean. So I rephrase the narrower question which could be:  How should one deal with several (analogous) data sets or source code files that have almost the same functionality. But feel free also to tell me how **you** interpreted the "question in the middle there"!